# Which Java Ide has toolbox like visual studio?

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio, toolbox

I am new in Java but not in programming..So,I have been using Visual Studio with visual basic programming language but now I want to learn Java and I want to know if there is a Java IDE with Visual Studio toolbox(watch the picture)
At the moment, I am using Eclipse for Java,,but it doesn't have Visual Studio toolbox. Thank's for help!

[image: Visual Studio toolbox].

Comment: you could switch to netbeans

Comment: Yes, its a good idea..Thank's!

Comment: @TechTechnology before migrating check the edit to my answer, migration may bring some headache :)

Comment: @TechTechnology: I stated it as an option, I wouldn't call it a "good idea" per se, though. The code generated by NetBeans is crappy, hard to read, and, if your UI has to change later on, a hell to maintain without introducing regression bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WindowBuilder plugin for Eclipe. More info here:
https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comment to the other answer, if you do not like WindowBuilder you can give a try to [JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/ides/eclipse/)

Comment: For now,I am downloading the WindowBuilder plugin for Eclipe.And then, if I don't like it I will install netbeans or JFormDesigner.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans IDE

The Smarter and Faster Way to Code

Quickly and easily develop desktop, mobile and web applications
with Java, HTML5, PHP, C/C++ and more.
NetBeans IDE is FREE, open source, and has a worldwide community
of users and developers.
[image: NetBeans GUI]

Comment: Am I wrong, of what you're just showing us is [this](http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/ides/eclipse/) plugin, which is also available for eclipse(so the author does not have to migrate all his work.

Comment: here is what the author said :" I want to know if there is a Java IDE with Visual Studio toolbox" he didn't said if there is a plugin for eclipse but thanks anyway I didn't know there is such a plugin :)

Comment: No worries.. I prefer Eclipse, as most of the plugins or features available to other IDEs sooner or later come to eclipse as well. And because of this you end up with an IDE with loads of possibilities :)